# Open Fragment in PagerSlidingTabStrip Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using `Sherlock` for `SliderMenu` and `PagerSlidingTabStrip`.
Now, They are setting `TextView` to `FrameLayout` when anyone clicks on Tab.
**Code :**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        fl.setLayoutParams(params);

        final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics());

        TextView v = new TextView(getActivity());
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_card);
        v.setText("CARD " + (position + 1));

        fl.addView(v);
        return fl;
    }
```

But here, bases on Position I want to open Fragment. How to do this ?

For i.e. I want to open Home

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
}
```